# How do I decrease width between text?

Tags: html, css

I was wondering how I could decrease the width between my text so the text was lined up like the following example below. Look at the text "Welcome to my portolfio". http://christopherc.ca

Here is my code so far,you can see the big gap between "Welcome to my" and "Portfolio" when you run it.

Below is my HTML

```
<h1 class="title4">WELCOME TO MY</h1>
<h1 class="title5">PORTFOLIO</h1>
```

Below is my CSS

```
.title4 {
text-align:middle;
font-family:Arial;
color:white;
font-size:45pt;
text-align:center;
}
.title5 {
text-align:middle;
font-family:Arial;
color:white;
font-size:45pt;
text-align:center;
}
```

Kind Regards,
Liam.

Comment: Vertical gap? `<h1>` elements have a default top and bottom margin that you have to override.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mention width and people keep offering ways to adjust the margin between the two titles. You can also change the spacing between letters.

If you add `letter-spacing: 2px;` to the h1 for "PORTFOLIO, you can expand the space between letters so that PORTFOLIO better matches the width of "WELCOME TO MY". In my sample using your code, I added 5px to better demonstrate the effect.

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
}


.title {
  text-align:middle;
  font-family:Arial;
  color:white;
  font-size:45pt;
  text-align:center;
  margin: 0;
}
.title2 {
  text-align:middle;
  font-family:Arial;
  color:white;
  font-size:45pt;
  text-align:center;
  margin: 0;
  letter-spacing: 5px;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <body>
       <h1 class="title">WELCOME TO MY</h1>
       <h1 class="title2">PORTFOLIO</h1>
    </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `margin: 0;` to each other your classes.

Also it's worth mentioning how much duplicated stuff you have. There is no difference between `title4` and `title5`. Why not make them the same class?

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
}


.title {
  text-align:middle;
  font-family:Arial;
  color:white;
  font-size:45pt;
  text-align:center;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <body>
       <h1 class="title">WELCOME TO MY</h1>
       <h1 class="title">PORTFOLIO</h1>
    </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
.title4 {
text-align:middle;
font-family:Arial;
color:red;
font-size:45pt;
text-align:center;
margin-bottom:0px;
}
.title5 {
text-align:middle;
font-family:Arial;
color:red;
font-size:45pt;
text-align:center;
margin-top: 0px
}
```

Comment: It would help if you explain the differences between the OP's code and what you've provided here.

Answer (score 0):

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
}

.title4 {
  font-family: Arial;
  color: white;
  font-size: 45pt;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0px;
}
.title5 {
  font-family: Arial;
  color: white;
  font-size: 45pt;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0px;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1 class="title4">WELCOME TO MY</h1>
    <h1 class="title5">PORTFOLIO</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can modify the height between your two divs by adding:

```
padding-top: -15px;
```

To your .title5 class. Here's a working fiddle with the above mentioned change: https://jsfiddle.net/h6s7fg3m/1/

Also, make sure you read the differences between padding and margin, as they are different and can come quite in handy.

Comment: Why add a negative padding instead of overriding the default margins?